# Driving a 74HC series chip with a 74LS series

Tags: logic-gates

I made a mistake and accidentally bought a 74LS AND gate[: this one](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sdls033/sdls033.pdf).  My other chips are 74HCs. I need the output of one of the AND gates to drive the clock signal on a JK flip-flop[: this one](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc109.pdf).  Unfortunately, the LS chip floats like crazy and I get random clock signals.  Is there anything I can do to make sure that the LS chip behaves (that is, doesn't float and cause spurious signals) or do I just need a new chip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HC chip needs >70% Vcc for the high voltage, which an LS gate is not guaranteed to deliver.

Use a pullup resistor on the output of the LS. Its output is rated to sink 8mA, so you can go down as far as a 620ohm resistor, though a higher value will use less current in the low state. 1k is a reasonable value to try. You cannot go too high in value, otherwise the pullup speed into load capacitance will be too slow and still not fix your multiple clock transitions. You will need to experiment with this if you want to use less current.

Comment: Thanks.  Using too much current isn't a huge deal, it's on a big benchtop power supply at the moment and, once I make it on a PCB instead of a breadboard I'll use the right chip anyway

Comment: The pull-up resistor is a recommended solution, but it is a bit slow: if the flip-flop clocking frequency is high, rising edge speed may be compromised.

Answer (score 2):

The Op should validate Vin/out for TTL and HC Logic. The common spec to satisfy both is Vil,Vol=<0.8V or Vih,Voh=>3.3V . The TTL input threshold is 1.3V but draws a few mA for lower voltage input for noise immunity.

Yet CMOS conducts almost 30 to 50mA for 10ns or so during each clock edge so it needs the 0.1uF to reduce ground and supply noise.

TTL Logic is low impedance for “0” with a current gain of at least 10. (Fanout) and high impedance above 2V so the pullup R and CMOS input capacitance (xx pF)  limits the rise time here (ns) , which you can find in the datasheet.  1k pullup is nominal but this can be modified to suit your speed and Vol spec.

Comment: I will definitely check, but it seems to be unambiguous that the LS chip is just not the right one for the job.  I'm going to try to get an HC chip soon and use that instead

Comment: For CMOS that is TTL compatible they have 74HCT

Answer (score 1):

It's not floating, but an LS TTL chip does not have a very high logic `1' voltage so the output may not look valid to a 74HC input. If you don't want to replace any chips, try adding a pullup resistor of about 1k\$\Omega\$ on the AND gate output.

Comment: thanks.  I do indeed have a 1K on the output and it's not doing much.  What I'm seeing is that the output correctly drives the HC high when required, but then it's driving it high randomly as well even if the two inputs to the LS's and gates are low. I've tried pull downs on the inputs (10K and 1K) but the problem persisted

Comment: Do you have bypass capacitors on all of your logic chips? You may be seeing noise from the power rails.

Comment: I do not, but I can add them.  What would be a good value? I should have a bunch of 10pF and some 10nFs as well.  Where would they go? Directly between Vcc pin and rails?

Comment: Use 10nF between Vcc and GND as close to the IC as possible, on every IC. Make sure there is a ground conductor running parallel with every clock line.

Comment: The capacitors should go directly from Vdd to Vss on every package with the shortest leads possible. Values of 10nF or 100nF are common.

Answer (score 1):

The 74HC has an amplifier (CMOS Nch+Pch) input, thus MILLER EFFECT will briefly steal charge from the 74LS.

At room temperature, you should expect the 74LS to be able to sink FAR MORE than the rated 8mA.

Assume 20mA, and simply install a 250 Ohm pullup.